# aws s3 shared bucket management

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a common dev project(node.js) with below setup:

> - developer-group-1 (country A, under 10 members)
> - developer-group-2 (country B, under 10 members)
> - server
> - they are sharing one S3 bucket

The problem is that each developer creates bunch of files stacking up in a shared bucket.

It goes like:

> Bucket/images
>
> ├ xxyy.png created by user A of dev-group-1
>
> ├ xyxz.png created by user B of dev-group-1
>
> ├ xxxx.png created by user C of dev-group-1
>
> ├ xxxy.png created by user D of dev-group-2
>
> ├ xxxz.png created by user E of dev-group-2
>
> ├ xxxk.png created by user F of dev-group-2
>
> └ ... thousands more

Each developer would create thousands of images/jsons this way.  It is hard to manage and impossible to empty the ever-growing bucket because I can't know which file/folder is being used.

Here is my best guess to fix this situation:

> 1. create IAM for each developers. (dev-A, dev-B, dev-C, ...)
> 2. notify each developer with created credentials information
> 3. when the project launch, create a temp bucket for locally specified IAM credential
> 4. add a life span policy for objects in bucket. Delete after inactive for a month

Please correct me If I am going wrong direction.

Comment: Does each developer work on an independent stack (with a separate copy of the application)? If so, give them their own S3 bucket. Are you sure that it is okay to delete S3 objects after a month? If so, it doesn't matter who created them, since they will be deleted anyway. Feel free to Edit your question to provide additional details.

Comment: 1. yes, I think I should give a bucket for each developer. For example, when the project launch, it creates a bucket named after username of Ubuntu or something.
2.  yes, one month is more than enough.  Each developer would launch project on their local PC only to confirm that commit is fail safe.  So I would guess no single task is taking longer than a month

Comment: What I am not sure is the guess I wrote above which is only from my head.  So I have no clue what experienced professionals in stackoverflow would do in such cases.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a bucket is virtually free. You can create 2 buckets for `dev-group-1` and `2` and apply an IAM Policy to the IAM groups.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Creating common bucket for `dev-group-1` and `dev-group-2` would still suffer from the same problem, wouldn't it?